# replacing all the column values (delimited by comma) with a function ouput in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df=pd.DataFrame(data={'name': ["sa","ad","ad"],
   'ID': [67,23,65],
   'code':["c.577A>T","c.577A>T,c.522A>T",np.nan]})
```

> ```
>  name  ID               code
> 0   sa  67           c.577A>T
> 1   ad  23  c.577A>T,c.522A>T
> 2   ad  65                NaN
> ```

I would like to apply the following function to all the values of the third column (delimited by ",")

```
def convert_c_to_g(inp):
    inp = 1
    return inp
```

I have been trying the following to no avail.

```
df.iloc[:,2] = df.iloc[:,2].apply(lambda x: 
    ','.join(convert_c_to_g(y) 
        for y in x.split(','))
            if pd.notna(x)
        else np.nan)
```

The desired output would be:

> ```
>  name  ID         code
> 0   sa  67           1
> 1   ad  23         1,1
> 2   ad  65         NaN
> ```

Comment: I think you need map `input_dict = {'c.577A>T' : 1}` ; `df['code'].map(input_dict)`

Comment: I just tried but wasn''t able to resolve it with `map`. The actual convert_c_g() function is more complicated so I replaced everything with return inp=1 int the question body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some problem in the `join` and it should be

```
df.iloc[:,2].apply(lambda x: 
    ','.join([str(convert_c_to_g(y) ) # see the [ and the str as well
        for y in x.split(',')])       # here you close the list comprehension with ]
            if pd.notna(x)
        else np.nan)
```

but if you want to apply the function where it is not `nan` directly, you could do it with creating a mask:

```
mask = df['code'].notna()
df.loc[mask, 'code'] = df.loc[mask, 'code'].apply(lambda x: ','.join([str(convert_c_to_g(y) )
                                                                      for y in x.split(',')]))
```